# de-increment by multiples? ; "do nothing"; create a division or division-like algorithm

Tags: python, increment

Still working on the beer problem.  Starting over.  I'm trying to not buy half beers, so here's where I got started:

```
#import math

def buybeers(wallet):
    beers = 0
    for(int in xrange(0,wallet,2)) #xrange not defined
        beers += 1
        wallet -= 2
    return beers, wallet

wallet = int(input("How many wallet do you have?"))

print(buybeers(wallet))
```

I'm trying to figure out how to buy one beer for ever 2 dollars and return the odd dollar.

Second attempt, trying to find the logical error:

```
def buybeers(wallet):
    beers = 0
    for i in range(1,wallet,3):
        beers += 1
        wallet -= 3
    return beers, wallet

wallet = int(input("How many wallet do you have?"))

print(buybeers(wallet))
```

An issue comes up when I have 14 dollars. I end up with -1 dollars and 5 beers (a beer I shouldn't have and a dollar owed).  Although it's correct, some convenience stores don't accept tabs.

### final submission (beers cost 3 bucks)

```
def buybeers(wallet):
    beers = 0
    for i in range(1,wallet,3):
        if wallet >= 3:  #if you got enough for a beer, buy one.
            beers += 1
            wallet -= 3
    #else:
    #    pass #otherwise, "do nothing"/pass (it seems this is automated).
    return beers, wallet

wallet = int(input("How many wallet do you have?"))

print(buybeers(wallet))
```

Comment: This code has a(t least 1) syntax error.

Comment: Fix this line: `for(int in xrange(0,wallet,2)` to `for i in xrange(0,wallet,2):`

Comment: @ScottHunter that's why i posted it.

Comment: No need to import math if you only do addition and subtraction.

Comment: Getting "xrange not defined"

Comment: You’re using Python 3, use just `range()` then instead of `xrange()`.

Comment: You don't need the if statement. It does nothing but add more to read

Comment: @SirParselot ust add in an if statement to check if you have enough money for the beer and if not do nothing. – SirParselot  <that's you, dude.  It prevents me from getting negative wallet values.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Oh woops I meant the else statement. Definitely keep the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few missing parentheses and your logic is wrong. Lets say you have `$5` and each beer costs `$2` then you can have `2` beers and have `$1` left over, however, your code will give you `3` beers and now you owe another dollar. You can simplify this by using division and modulus like so

```
def buybeers(wallet):
    beers = wallet//2
    wallet = wallet % 2

    return beers, wallet

wallet = int(input("How many wallet do you have?"))

print(buybeers(wallet)) #5 as input

(2, 1)
```

Just fixing the syntax errors you get

```
def buybeers(wallet):
    beers = 0
    for i in xrange(0,wallet,2):
        beers += 1
        wallet -= 2
    return beers, wallet

wallet = int(input("How many wallet do you have?"))

print(buybeers(wallet)) #5 as input

(3, -1)
```

Which won't give you the correct output since your for loop logic is off.

Comment: is the second one going to make a mistake, also, due to logic?  Can you highlight the logical error, so I can try to fix that?  Also, I'm still getting xrange not defined from that second block.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 the second one is just fixing the syntax errors while keeping your logic, which is flawed. Notice how the output is `(3, -1)`

Comment: but the modulus example is also logically flawed for the reason I posted this question.  If you go for 11 wallets, you get 5.5 beers and 1 wallet.  You should get 5 beers and 1 wallet.  Imagine if a beer cost 7 dollars, then you could get 6/7's of a beer or whatever

Comment: I don't see the logical error, but I'm getting the output you mentioned.  Is it just because I'm starting at 0 instead of 1?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 oh that's my bad. I'm using 2.7 which `/` is integer division but in 3.3 `//` is integer division

Comment: sirparselot that's great.  How do I stop owing cash, though? ^^

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 wash dishes until you've paid off your debt. Haha not really, just add in an if statement to check if you have enough money for the beer and if not do nothing.

Comment: Can you +1? The purpose is to _create a division or division-like algorithm_.  Good work, Sirparselot (py 2 and 3)